# Map spring rest controller to a path without the servlet context

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with the following context path:

```
server.servlet.context-path:/api
```

I need to write a rest controller that's mapped to 
http://localhost:8080/logout
instead of http://localhost:8080/api/logout

Is there a way to achieve this? changing the "server.servelt.context-path" value is not an option.

this is what I tried and didn't work:

```
@GetMapping(value="../signout"){
public void logout(){
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Comment: No, it's not possible. You both want a different context path, and refuse to change the one you use.

Comment: When you set the context path... you are saying your whole application falls under that path

Comment: What is the issue with `http://localhost:8080/api/logout`

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this is /api is protected by our siteminder. But the logout url needs to be an unprotected path as per the siteminder SME. Hence the need to not have context path in the logout url

Comment: Not sure what `siteminder` is .... but you could explicitly remove security on the `../api/logout` path

Comment: Although anybody logging out should have already been logged in? 

Comment: Probably [SiteMinder](https://www.broadcom.com/products/software/cybersecurity/identity-and-access-management/layer7-siteminder), @RobOhRob.

Answer (score 1):

Nero, you say you can't change the "server.servlet.context-path" value. I bet you say this because you don't want to break the API, but I think you can manage to change this without breaking the API. Set the context-path to blank, which is permitted. Then in your application change the "api" mapping, which I assume is currently "/", to "api".

1. Change `server.servlet.context-path:/api` to `server.servlet.context-path:/` or maybe `server.servlet.context-path:` (no slash). (Supposedly this is the default so you might just remove this entry altogether.)
2. Somewhere in your application change `@RequestMapping("/")` to `@RequestMapping("/api")`.

Now you can also have `@GetMapping(value="/signout")` and you will have resources at http://localhost:8080/logout and http://localhost:8080/api.

I don't know what mapping annotations you happen to be using, but hopefully this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be possible within that application to go outside its context root. Maybe you can create a separate Rest service app for that particular url and take it from there.